# How to reset the Angularjs ui-select component all selections without red color error highlight when ui-select marked as required

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-select

I'm trying to reset all selection of angularjs ui-select.

> but ui-select marked as required field

.so that when I set the ui-select element as undefined as shown below.

```
$scope.country.selected = undefined;
```

ui-select element indicates a validation error with red colour.Anyway, i want to reset selection without prompting validation error with the existing required attribute.

[image]

```
<ui-select required ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
      <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
      <button class="clear" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: You can use `set pristine` to reset the style

Comment: @Icycool  can you show code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Add a form as bellow then you can setPristine to reinitialize the status of the form (You can also see the plunker link to see the working example):

```
<form name="formName" novalidate>
    <h3>Selectize theme</h3>
    <p>Selected: {{country.selected}}</p>
    <ui-select required ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
        <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
        <button class="clear" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.clear = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation(); 
    $scope.country.selected = undefined;
    $scope.formName.$setPristine();
};
```

You can see the [Working example plunker in here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VaKfWp2k3LTgdZkeDrVv?p=preview)

The angular 1.3 introduced the touched concept:

**touched vs pristine**: touched means the field has been blurred while pristine means the field's value has been modified. Angular's docs note that "Setting a form controls back to their untouched state is often useful when setting the form back to its pristine state."

```
$scope.formName.$setUntouched()
```

I hope this can help

Comment: Where do you get this error (I mean the context) ? because $event in this example is just a jQuerry event passed to the function. And to access to this parameter, you should passed it throught you callback parameter.